# Filter a RDD by some other RDD[both RDDs have different type] in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 RDDs:

```
Rdd1:(String,CompactBuffer)
 (3,CompactBuffer(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
 (4,CompactBuffer(2, 4))
 (1,CompactBuffer(1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9))
 (5,CompactBuffer(1, 8)) 
 (2,CompactBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9))



Rdd2:(String,Long)
 (1,6) 
 (2,7) 
 (3,6)
```

I want to filter Rdd1 by the keys of Rdd2 i.e. only the entries with the same keys should be saved. Let's say Rdd2 have 3 (key,value) pairs, means 3 keys i.e. 1,2 and 3. So i need only the (key,value) pairs in Rdd1, which have the same keys kept in Rdd2. So the expected result is as follows:

```
Rdd3:(String, CompactBuffer)
(3,CompactBuffer(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)) 
(1,CompactBuffer(1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9)) 
(2,CompactBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Rdd1.join(Rdd2).map(x => x._1 -> x._2._1)
```

Comment: join operation gives the error because both the Rdd's have different value type i.e. in Rdd1, its 'compactBuffer' while in Rdd2, its 'long'.

Comment: Actually, above given is not code part, i simply has given the content of both Rdds and the expected result.